# Center text in the TextView of a RecyclerView row

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app. Below's an xml code of its row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="-1.5dp"
        android:paddingTop="-1.5dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/text_with_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_with_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="77dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..."
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The Android Studio preview shows that it looks like on the following screenshot:
[image: custom row template]

So, it looks like the letter in the red circle is well centered and here comes the first problem. In the screenshot from an emulator it is easy to notice that all the letters in those circles are not in the center. How can I center them?
[image: Emulator screenshot]

And now the second issue. In the emulator screenshot if you look at the third item of the list ("Something3"), it has no description text below the text in bold. Is is possible to vertically center it in the row if there's no description?
Circles in the list are backgrounds of the textview and are shapes in separate xml file (circle.xml):

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: use `LinearLayout`  then `gravity` then center verticall, then catch  the text of the textview if it is empty the you set it to visibility gone.. `RelativeLayout` will also do with center in parent.. (i am refering to the textviews on the right)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understood...
I've tried Linear Layout first, but couldn't achieve appropriate positioning of the elements. Then I've tried Relative Layout and all the elements went crazy and posotioned randomly and I didn't succeed in positioning them normally. Frame layout was the only one I could position elements with:( Could you explain your answer in more words, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the **more words**, look at the `TextView` with id `android:id="@+id/description"` and check its `Visiblity` , it is set to `gone` if you set it to `visible` both `TextView` 's will be in the middle, but if `gone` your above `TextView` is always on top like what you see.. and the magic continues with `Gravity`.. (I'm referring to this solution)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_with_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="-1.5dp"
    android:paddingTop="-1.5dp"
    android:text="A"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_with_icon"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Dummy text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..."
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in your `getView()` or java side, check if the string is empty or not so

```
if(!TextView.getText().toString().isEmpty()){ // if it is not empty
    TextView.setVisibility(0); // zero means visible..
}
```

if you are targeting below api 9 the put this in the if statement `TextView.getText().toString().length() != 0`